# Check Application Cache from PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, html5-appcache

I am developping a web app which will be distributed to Android and iOS using PhoneGap 3.3.

When the app starts I check whether the user is online and if the server is reachable. If not I show an offline page which was added to the PhoneGap app. Once the web app is downloaded (it uses AppCache) I want to show it's own offline page if internet isn't deactivated.

So what I try to achieve is showing the PhoneGap offline page when the internet access is disabled or there is no AppCache offline page. The problem is how to find out if the AppCache offline page exists. I haven't found a way to search the AppCache, and window.applicationCache.status simply returns 0 (uncached).

Can anybody give me a hint about this?